# vue.reactive is not a function

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

I tried to migrate a vue project to a nuxt project. The problem is using `store/index.js` file.

I copied the origin file into store folder and this error occurs. I could't find the reason.
[image]

`store/index.js`

```js
import { createStore } from "vuex";

export default createStore({
  state: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`createStore`](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/api/#createstore) is a method of Vuex4, which is aimed towards Vue3.
If you want to use Vuex4, you'll need to use Nuxt3 (which is as of today, not 100% production-ready overall but may still be okay for a smaller project IMO).

Comment: Thank you. Then how can I use nuxt3?

Comment: You can check the preview of Nuxt3 here: https://preview.nuxtjs.org/v3/ Type in `nuxt` and `nuxt` and you'll see the ETA of Nuxt3. It should be available in August, until then you're stuck with Nuxt2.

Comment: So unable to fix this error? I mean I need to use vuex in the project.

Comment: Do you need to use Vuex4? You could use Vuex3, which is compatible and already available out of the box. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#activate-the-store

Comment: I installed the vuex using npm install vuex@next. Can you give me any hints about how to install vuex3?

Comment: As told in my previous comment, Vuex is already baked into Nuxt. Please read the first line of the link that I gave you. Every info on how to use Vuex with Nuxt is available there! @sirius

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried Vuex.Store, too. It does not work either. I just want to know how to install vuex3.

Comment: @sirius Reading the first line: `The Vuex Store comes with Nuxt.js out of the box`. Vuex3 is **ALREADY** installed in your Nuxt app. You don't have to do anything at all to get started.